# How to add coordinates from db to Marker react leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

From the database, I receive coordinates that lie in the form of two fields: "lat" and "lon". On the map I use several makers. How can I combine these two fields to pass coordinates(coord.lat and coord.lon) to the Marker component at position? I tried to add, but you can't pass values ​​to props separated by commas.

```js
const Map = () => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "map-markers"));
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setCoordinates(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <MapContainer
        center={center}
        zoom={13}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        {coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
          <Marker key={index} position={coord.lat, coord.lon} icon={defaultIcon} />
        ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the `coordinates`  you received from db please

Comment: Added a screenshot from the database

Comment: I need to see the formate of the data you received

Answer (score 1):

A React-Leaflet Marker gets its position data in a float array with two values:

`[51.234, 23.654]`

So you would first need to get the latitude and longitude in an array as floats - it seems in your data format you have the coordinates as float-formatted strings in the `lat` and `lon` properties so you could do it like so:

`const position = [parseFloat(coord.lat), parseFloat(coord.lon)]`

Then you would just pass this array as the property:

`<Marker key={index} position={position} icon={defaultIcon} />`

So the whole block of populating markers from the coordinates list would be something like:

```
{coordinates.map((coord, index) => {
    const position = [parseFloat(coord.lat), parseFloat(coord.lon)]
    return <Marker key={index} position={position} icon={defaultIcon} />
)}
```

Or you could just inline it (to avoid writing a full function body for the map) like:

```
{coordinates.map((coord, index) => (
          <Marker key={index} position={[parseFloat(coord.lat), parseFloat(coord.lon)]} icon={defaultIcon} />
        ))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where do I need to declare the position variable? inside map()?

Comment: Yes - I added some more complete examples on how to do that.

Comment: Thank you. I added a screenshot from the console after I implemented your solution

Comment: Check that your `coord` object is populated with the `lat` and `lon` properties (they exist and are float-formatted strings) as the proposed solution expects. Otherwise you will have to modify the proposed solution.

Comment: The screenshot I attached shows the structure of my collection. But when I try to output console.log(coord.lat) to the console, it shows me 4 times "undefined"